# Over 5000 items in SP 2010, what happens?

Tags: 2010, list-view-threshold

We have a SP site, and it have around 5400 items. I'm trying to figure out what happens to the SP site when the item count is over 5000(threshold).

After searching on the internet, I can't find all the limitations when the item count is over 5000.

What I have experienced personally is that when I created a view it only shows some of the actual results. 
And I get this message in the top of the custom view:

> Displaying only the newest results below. To view all results, narrow your query by adding a filter.

Does someone have a list or something with the consequences when the item count exceeds 5000?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers are listed by MS because they have been proved in performance tests in MS test labs. So, by all means, the limits mentioned in the capacity boundaries section at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12438.sharepoint-2013-best-practices.aspx#Capacity_Planning are realistic and can be met. You can store huge amounts of items in a list (up to 30.000.000 per list), but don't get more than 5000 in one go. Once you get close to that limit, you'll see performance degrade more and more.

I guess the reason there are so many links warning about this is that SharePoint is a complex product. We often come in situations where a client asks to fix bad SharePoint performance. Quite often, this is caused by skipping capacity planning and organizing SharePoint in a way it shouldn't.Just see this link it is a very good post explaining thresholds,

http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/6614983:BlogPost:32763

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not allowed to change the threshold. I'm looking for the consequences of exceeding the threshold of 5000.

Comment: The consequences are that you are not able to display listview-webparts
 anymore and certain queries as SiteDataQuery for example won't work anymore.

Comment: @Bjorn Just go through this link,  http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/6614983:BlogPost:32763